# Concatenar mais valores em um value de um input no form blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, template

Tenho Dúvida como posso concatenar mais valores em um mesmo input no value de um form usando blade.

Exemplo:

```
<input type="hidden" name="produto"  value="{{ $produto->descricao}}">
```

Estou enviando somente descrição, porém gostaria de concatenar no mesmo value do input :

```
o nome do produto {{$produto->nome}};
o código {{$produto->codigo}};
a data {{$produto->data}};
o preço {{$produto->preco}}
```

Seria essa minha dúvida. Obrigado

Comment: só usar concatenação.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

olá, eu não sei se entendi bem oque você precisa, mas se for concatenar todo esse texto no value do input faria da seguinte forma :

```
<input type="hidden" name="produto"  value="{{ 'o nome do produto .' .$produto->descricao .'o código '.$produto->codigo.'a data '.$produto->data.'o preço '.$produto->preco}}">
```

porém acredito que com um textarea ficaria melhor, já que com alguns "\n" você conseguiria quebrar linhas para formatar melhor o texto.

Comment: Isso Vinicius, ele me retornou um valor sem quebra de linha, como posso fazer mesmo? trocando de input para textarea e usando "\n" dentro do value do input ele quebraria, correto?

Comment: não exatamente, eu me equivoquei, assim ficará como você gostaria  ```<textarea name="produto">{{"o nome do produto ." .$produto->descricao."
o código ".$produto->codigo."
a data ".$produto->data."
o preço ".$produto->preco}}</textarea>```

Comment: Certo, assim mesmo, agora está de acordo com a necessidade. Muito Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Olá, tudo bem?

Então, amigo, você também pode concatenar utilizando outra forma permitida dentro do Laravel. Caso utilize este framework.

```
<input type="hidden" name="produto"  value="A descrição do produto é {{$produto->descricao}}, o nome do produto é {{$produto->nome}}, o código é {{$produto->codigo}} ">
```

Qualquer dúvida só comentar aqui em baixo.

Abraços.